# Execute Context Menu Command in External Application

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, winapi, handler

I am trying to write an application that can select all text in the textbox within an external application, copy it to the clipboard, perform changes programmatically to the string and then send the modified string back to the external application. I did not write the external application and do not have access to its code nor can I afford to contact the developer and have them make changes. The external application is Client-Server based and I can only interact with the user interface on the client side.

The problem I am running into is that I can easily send keyboard commands to the application to send or delete text, but I cannot select all of the text. Using keyboard shortcuts Ctrl-A, Ctrl-Shift-Home, Ctrl-Shift-End, etc. do not work. Triple clicking on the text box does not work either.

However, I can right click on the text box and bring up a context menu and then select the command "Select All". I am wondering if there is a way to send the context menu command to the application without having to have the context menu appear.

I want the two applications to appear to be working as seamlessly as possible to the user. Does anyone have any suggestions that might work?

Comment: You are trying too hard. Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) if you want to automate a UI.

Comment: I will definitely look into it! I didn't see this class mentioned in any of my google searches. Will respond again once I've had a chance to mess around with it. Thanks!

Comment: UI Automation can be overkill for simple tasks. You could alternatively use the `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT` messages instead. Either way, there is no need to involve the clipboard, and thus no need to select the text (you can use `EM_SETSEL` for that) before retrieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

> I am wondering if there is a way to send the context menu command to the application without having to have the context menu appear.

When a menu item is clicked, it issues a `WM_COMMAND` message to the parent window of the menu.  You can use a tool like Spy++ to monitor such messages and see which command ID is being sent to which window, and then you can code your app to send the same message directly to that same window.  No need to display the actual menu itself.

However, in this particular situation, that is overkill. If you have the HWND of the desired edit control, you can send it `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT` messages instead, or use .NET's UIAutomation interfaces, to get/set the control's text directly.  Either way, there is no need to select the text (you can use `EM_SETSEL` for that) or to involve the clipboard.